# "No value given" error in where clause of sql

Tags: sql, vba

Have the following code:

```
    Dim MasterIDIn As Double         'Use in where clause
    MasterIDIn = CDbl(Me!scanTxtBox.Value)

    Dim RCMSql As String
    RCMSql = "SELECT [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].MaxOfDate_of_Transaction," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].FirstName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].LastName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Email_Address," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Address_Line_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_2," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Date_Sent," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].CouponValue," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag " & _
    "FROM [Range Card Master Mailer] " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID)= MasterIDIn))"
     RCMRs.Open RCMSql                       'Fill the recordset
```

The open throws the error

> "No value given for one or more of the parameters"

If I remove the where clause it runs. The Master_ID field on the file is double so I convert the textbox value to double and seems that should work.  In the immediate window MasterIDin and CDbl(Me!scanTxtBox.Value) have the same values.
I must be missing something.

Thanks

Comment: I guess `MasterIDIn` should be a value, not passed in the string.

Comment: does this seem correct? [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID  = MasterIDIn

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically create the string to allow `MasterIDIn` to take it's value within the VBA code. At the moment you are actually looking for the `MasterID` 'MasterIDIn'.

```
Dim RCMSql As String
    RCMSql = "SELECT [Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].MaxOfDate_of_Transaction," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].FirstName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].LastName," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Email_Address," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Address_Line_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_1," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Phone_Number_2," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].Date_Sent," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].CouponValue," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemDate," & _
    "[Range Card Master Mailer].RedeemFlag " & _
    "FROM [Range Card Master Mailer] " & _
    "WHERE ((([Range Card Master Mailer].Master_ID)= " & MasterIDIn & "))"
     RCMRs.Open RCMSql                       'Fill the recordset
```

Comment: Got It,, Thanks so much